# Multiply decimal and a double in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

If I have a poco class

```
public class Entry
{
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I do arithmetic on them in a Linq query with something like

```
context.Entries.Sum(e => (decimal)e.Quantity * e.Cost);
```

I get Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Decimal'

Edit: I have cast the decimal to double and it works.

```
context.Entries.Sum(e => e.Quantity * (double)e.Cost);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this exception calling `.Sum()` on an array with a few manually constructed `Entry` instances.  Do you have a stack trace for the exception?  More code context you can provide?

Comment: By operator precedence `Quantity` should be converted to decimal & multiply by `Cost` (beware: use `AsEnumerable` if your query is LINQ to Entities). Can you provide exception details & stack trace?

Comment: Just an idea (I know it doesn't really provide an answer): you might be able to work around that problem by having your logic in a stored procedure in your database, which can be executed using linq to entities.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework is indicating it does not support the conversion you desire.To take your original query, you can make the following change:

```
context.Entries
.AsEnumerable() // perform rest of work in memory
.Sum(e => (decimal)e.Quantity * e.Cost);
```

Comment: That will bring all of the data in that table into memory! You should at least make a projection to only fetch the columns you're adding together.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek the OP did not wants to have a projection, if so he simply  could add a `Where` clause. His entity model has only two fields so I think there is no need to filter the columns.

Comment: No, the query is rather complex, I have simplified it quite a bit to ask the question. I really don't want to do it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Convert.ToDecimal()

```
context.Entries.Sum(d => Convert.ToDecimal(d.Quantity)*d.Cost)
```

[Here is working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BZWthH)

Edit as stated by Tetsuya Yamamoto if you are not using an enumrable collection

```
context.Entries.ToList().Sum(d => Convert.ToDecimal(d.Quantity)*d.Cost)
```

Comment: This may not work if OP's query is LINQ to Entities (does not recognize `ToDecimal` method). Use `AsEnumerable` before `Sum` to get it safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on performing all calculations at database side and you have problems with casting, you can use static methods of [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but of course, it will have performance overhead:

```
var result = context.Entries
     .Sum(x => SqlFunctions.Exp(SqlFunctions.Log(x.Quantity) + SqlFunctions.Log(x.Cost)));
```

> Explanation: e^(ln(Quantity) + ln(Cost)) = e^(ln(Quantity * Cost)) = Quantity *
>   Cost

Or you can try to write query manually:

```
var result = context.Database
     .SqlQuery<decimal>("select sum(Quantity * Cost) from dbo.Entries)").FirstOrDefault();
```